# Testing nullptr in Char Array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, null, char

This is bothering my a great deal, but I was trying to do an exercise for The C++ Programming Language exercises, and the question was to simply find the size and length of a char[] array, which I did, however it encounters problems when I try to verify that it's a valid pointer:

```
void size_length(const char* p, int& size, int& length)
{
    //I don't know why, but this causes all entries to return 0
    if (!p) size = 0; length = 0; return;
    //Copy the pointer, as I want the original intact
    const char* cp = p;
    while (*cp++) ++size; ++length;
    ++size; //Null character
    size *= sizeof(char); //For portability
}

int main()
{
    char* str{ new char[15]{"A short string"} };
    int s{ 0 }, l{ 0 };
    size_length(str, s, l);
    cout << "Size: " << s << endl << "Length: " << l << endl;
}
```

In the second line of size_length() when I try to verify I have a legal pointer, such as if I passed a free store nullptr, it causes ALL attempts to register as invalid and returns 0, 0 (I placed several statements on one line to save space here). I've tried variations of the statement and passed many different things, but it all returns 0, 0. If I remove the line, the program works fine, however!

If anyone could tell me what it is I'm doing wrong and/or why I shouldn't be testing for nullptr in apparently THIS specific circumstance (I'm trying to do the *right* thing by testing validity) I would appreciate it.

Comment: `if (!p) size = 0; length = 0; return;` => `if (!p) {size = 0; length = 0; return;}`. on the same line doesn't mean that it is in the `if` condition.

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, you should be aware that:

```
if (!p) size = 0; length = 0; return;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (!p)
    size = 0;
length = 0;
return;
```

In other words, it zeroes `length` and returns *no matter what!*

If your intent is to make all three statements conditional, you need:

```
if (!p) { size = 0; length = 0; return; }
```

which equates to:

```
if (!p) {
    size = 0;
    length = 0;
    return;
}
```

Ditto with:

```
while (*cp++) ++size; ++length;
```

in that the `++length` is currently executed *once* after the loop finishes.

And, as an aside, I love your statement "for portability" :-) By definition, `sizeof(char)` is *always* one so there's absolutely no reason why your code isn't portable without that identity multiplication.

Comment: Thank you so much (both of you). This is the first time I've ever placed multiple statements on a line to preserve vertical space, and I'm already paying for it. Never again! Such a foolish mistake.